# Difference between $F_2^n$ and $\Bbb F_2^n$ for a field

Tags: field-theory, information-theory, coding-theory

I am confused between the notation $F_2^n$ and $\Bbb F_2^n$ for a field in regards to codes.

I thought that $F_2^n$ and $\Bbb F_2^n$ were both fields composed by codes of length n and entries in mod 2, but I now know that this cannot be true.
What is the difference between them?

For example, if code C is consists of all the codewords in $F_n^2$ that have even weight, to show that C is a linear code, do I use the fact that it is a subspace of $F_2^n$ or $\Bbb F_2^n$?

Thank you!

Comment: $F_2^n$ just seems like the lazy-man's version of the $\mathbb{F}_2^n$ but without the context of where you are reading this it is hard to answer.

Comment: @E-A Thank you. In class, my professor wrote down that $F= \Bbb F_q$ and that $F^n= \Bbb F_q^n$, so I thought that $\Bbb F$ simply corresponded to the finite version of the field $F$. However, in the homework it seems that she uses $F$ and $\Bbb F$ interchangeably for finite fields. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't misinterpreting, thank you for your answer.

Comment: It seems likely that she is just calling the field $\mathbb{F}_q$ by the name $F$. Or maybe $F$ was defined previously in some other way, and she is just noting that said $F$ is actually equal to $\mathbb{F}_q$. This is just a guess.